# How to retrieve list of favorite tags that is sorted based on no of post tagged by it?

Tags: java, lambda

I am new to Java 8 **lambda expressions**.

I have a `List<Post>` where each `Post` can belong to multiple post.

```
class Post{
     String name;
     List<String> tags;
     ....
}
```

I want to retrieve list of favorite tags that is sorted based on no of post tagged by it. How to  achieve it using lambda expressions?

Sample Input in form of JSON that is stored in MongoDB:

```
[
    {
        "name": "java with spring",
        "tags": [
            "java",
            "spring"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "spring with mongodb",
        "tags": [
            "java",
            "spring",
            "mongodb"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "spring with hibernate",
        "tags": [
            "java",
            "spring",
            "hibernate"
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```
java,spring,mongodb,hibernate
```

---

Here is what I have tried after below answers:;

```
List<Post> posts = ...

List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

// get list of all tags
posts.stream().forEach(post -> tags.addAll(post.getTags()));
// populate map with tag and its count (frequency)
tags.stream().forEach(tag -> map.put(tag, map.get(tag) == null ? 1 : map.get(tag) + 1));

Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>> byValue = (entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue().compareTo(entry2.getValue());
// sort the map by value and return the sorted keys as favorite tags
List<String> favoriteTags =  map.entrySet().stream().sorted(byValue.reversed()).map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible to achieve this in one single expression, but it is possible to do this in two steps, by first constructing a map which counts the number of occurences of each tags :

```
Map<String, Integer> tags = new HashMap<>();
posts.forEach(p -> p.tags.forEach(t -> tags.put(t, tags.get(t) != null ? tags.get(t)+1 : 1)));
List<String> sortedTags = tags.entrySet().stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getValue() - e1.getValue()).map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes it is the simplified version of my last edit. Thanks

Comment: No problem, but I'm also quite new to Java 8 lambda expressions, and I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve this in one single expression. I'm pretty sure there is a way ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following approach:

```
static class Helper {
    String name;
    String tag;

    Helper(final String name, final String tag) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

}

static void getFavourites() {
    final List<String> favourites =
            new ArrayList<Post>().stream().<Helper> flatMap(p -> p.tags.stream().map(t -> new Helper(p.name, t)))
                    .collect(groupingBy(h -> h.tag, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1))).entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue()))
                    .map(e -> e.getKey())
                    .collect(toList());
}
```

(the  cast is only there because Eclipse complained).
The idea is to invert the mapping between posts and tags (which could also have been done using multimap), count the occurrences of the tags and sort them.

You have to replace the `new ArrayList<Post>()` with your actual data, of course.

Comment: very long expression. Let me try to understand it. I don't want to complex it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use lambda expressions because they can't really help.

I would otherwise use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) and then sort on count.

```
List<Post> posts = ... ;
Multiset<String> tags = HashMultiset.create();
posts.stream().forEach((p) -> tags.addAll(p.getTags()));
// Now we have the frequency. Let's sort it.
tags = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(tags);
// You want only the tags and nothing else? No problem
Set<String> strings = tags.elementSet();
```

Lambdas don't solve everything. Just use the right tool for the right task.

Comment: Thanks for help. I am looking for solution in Java itself but this is a good answer.